# How can I fix my coding, new to using string

Tags: c++

My assignment is to take a "tweet" and run it through the code getline(com, tweet) and find the abbreviations (e.g. BFF, FTW) and spew out the same "tweet" but with the first of the each encountered abbreviation defined. For example. A user enters a sentence with LOL twice in there, the first LOL should be laugh out loud when code is done. There is a limit of 160 characters for input as well. My code is doing something funny where It scrambles the definitions and the regurgitated text.  LOL that was funny becomes : laugh ful ny loud, something like so.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 string tweet;
 int lol = 0;
 int irl = 0;
 int afk = 0;
 int nvm = 0;
 int bff = 0;
 int ftw = 0;
 int iirc = 0;
 int ttyl = 0;
 int imho = 0;

 cout << "Enter abbreviation from tweet: \n";
 getline(cin,tweet);// Output decoded abbreviation from tweet

 tweet.resize(160);

 lol = tweet.find("LOL");
 irl = tweet.find("IRL");
 afk = tweet.find("AFK");
 nvm = tweet.find("NVM");
 ftw =tweet.find("FTW");
 bff = tweet.find("BFF");
 iirc = tweet.find("IIRC");
 ttyl = tweet.find("TTYL");
 imho = tweet.find("IMHO");


 if (lol >= 0) {
     tweet = tweet.replace(lol, 3, "laughing out loud");
     cout << endl;
     }
 if (irl >= 0 ) {
     tweet = tweet.replace(irl, 3, "in real life");
     cout << endl;
 }
 if (afk >= 0) {
    tweet = tweet.replace(afk, 3, "away from keyboard");
    cout << endl;
 }
 if (nvm >= 0) {
     tweet = tweet.replace(nvm, 3, "never mind");
     cout << endl;
 }
 if (bff >= 0) {
     tweet = tweet.replace(bff, 3, "best friends forever");
     cout << endl;
 }
 if (ftw >= 0) {
   tweet = tweet.replace(ftw, 3, "for the win");
   cout << endl;
 }
 if (iirc >= 0) {
   tweet = tweet.replace(iirc, 4, "if I recall correctly");
   cout << endl;
 }
 if (ttyl >=0) {
     tweet = tweet.replace(ttyl, 4, "talk to you later");
     cout << endl;
 }
 if (imho >= 0) {
     tweet = tweet.replace(imho, 4, "in my humble opinion");
     cout << endl;
 }
 cout << tweet;
 cout << endl;

 return 0;
```

}

Comment: So basically when you input, LOL My BFF, Maria is the best IRL, she played hard and FTW, LOL.   The output should be laugh out loud My best friend(s), Maria is the best in real life, she played hard and for the win, LOL.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, links to code, or broken links to code. Post the code as a [mcve].

Comment: How about the timeless tweet "VICTIMHOOD: KAFKA TWIRLS HIS GIFTWRAPPED LOLLIPOPS"?

Answer (score 2):

Your positions are off becuse you got them before you did any substitutions.
You're also doing at most one substitution per string.

But you're heading down the path of "copy-and-paste", which is not a good path to be on.

Instead, start with writing a function that replaces all occurrences of one string with another string.

```
std::string replace_all(std::string text, const std::string& src, const std::string& subst)
{
    int pos = text.find(src);
    while (pos != std::string::npos)
    {
        text.replace(pos, src.size(), subst);
        pos = text.find(src, pos + subst.size() + 1); 
    }
    return text;
}
```

Then use a table and a loop:

```
std::map<string, string> table = {{"LOL", "loads of loaves"}, {"BFF", "better fast food"}};
for (const auto& it: table)
    tweet = replace_all(tweet, it.first, it.second);
```

Answer (score 1):

You first search where the abbreviations occur and then replace them. After replacing the first abbreviation the locations you've previously found will be wrong.

Say the string is: `LOL BFF`. So lol location is 0 and bff location is 4. Now you replace lol, so the string is 'laughing out loud BFF', so the bff location (4) is wrong you need to search for it again to get the correct location.

To fix it move the find just before the if and replace.

Also to check if the search succeeded you should compare like `location != string::npos`.

Comment: Thank you!! That makes sense, and it fixed the  bug. I'm still learning this and it gets very confusing !